# Retrieving data from table 1 using table 2 in the order of table 2 data

Tags: sql, sql-server, matching

I have two tables JOB and EMP; values are like this

```
CREATE TABLE JOB (JOBID SMALLINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,JOBNAME CHAR(15));

CREATE TABLE EMP(EMPID SMALLINT, JOBID SMALLINT, SAL SMALLINT, CITYID 
       SMALLINT,YEAR SMALLINT,STATUS CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO JOB(JOBID, JOBNAME) VALUES
        ( 1, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
        (2, 'DEVELOPMENT'),
        (3,'TESTING'),
        (4,'TESTING'),
        (7,'TESTING'),
        (9,'RESEARCH'),
        (8,'HR');

INSERT INTO EMP (EMPID , JOBID, SAL,CITYID,YEAR,STATUS) VALUES
   (  100,1,1000,10,2015,'A'),
   (  200,2,2000,10.2015,'A'),
   (  300,1,2500,20,2015,'E'),
   (  400,3,1000,10,2016,'A'),
   (  500,6,3000,10,2015,'E'),
   (  600,8,1000,30,2015,'A'),
   (  700,8,2000,10,2015,'A'),
   (  800,9,1500,20,2015,'A')
;
```

I want to display all jobname count and avg salaries; for the jobname if jobid's not exists then display 0

For the given input cityid , YEAR and STATUS ( Emp table), take all jobids for each jobname (from job table ) and match in Emp table, if exists display count (count of jobids present in Emp table) and avgsal else 0 for count and avgsal.

Output should be like this for Cityid's 10 and 20 year 2015 status 'A'

```
Cityid  jobname        count avg-sal
10       development    2     1500
10       TESTING        0       0
10       RESEARCH       0       0
10       HR             1      2000
10      total           3      1666.66
20      development     0         0
20      Testing         0         0
20      Research        1      1500
20      HR              0         0
20      Total           1     2500
Grand Total             4     1625
```

I tried thru joins, but didnt work properly;
Is it better use joins or Cursor ?

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: it is sql   server           .

Comment: post your select script and it's output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you want, you need to first `CROSS JOIN` all the jobs with all the desired `CITYID` values, and then you can `LEFT JOIN` that to the `EMP` table and SUM the jobs and average the salaries, using a `ROLLUP` clause to get your totals:

```
SELECT C.CITYID,
       j.JOBNAME,
       COUNT(e.CITYID) AS count,
       COALESCE(AVG(e.SAL), 0) AS "avg-sal"
FROM JOB J
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CITYID
            FROM EMP
            WHERE CITYID IN (10, 20)) C
LEFT JOIN EMP e ON e.JOBID = j.JOBID AND e.CITYID = C.CITYID
GROUP BY ROLLUP (C.CITYID, j.JOBNAME)
```

Output:

```
CITYID  JOBNAME         count   avg-sal
10      DEVELOPMENT     2       1500
10      HR              1       2000
10      RESEARCH        0       0
10      TESTING         1       1000
10                      4       1500
20      DEVELOPMENT     1       2500
20      HR              0       0
20      RESEARCH        0       0
20      TESTING         0       0
20                      1       2500
                        5       1700
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d5760f45babe4bedee9c1f3e2da89bbb)

Comment: Nick -Thank you ; I verified with some data, its working; will verify for some more  data

Comment: Nick - if I add year and status conditions also along with cityid, it is not retrieving correct values if cityid exists and year and status condition fails.

Comment: @SRI but that is changing the question which is a bit unfair... anyway all you have to do is add those conditions to the `LEFT JOIN` condition and it works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4a8f7543470aa33b5244cfe24e0df50c

Comment: Nick - Thank you. Its working as expected. But I've one question - Lets say I've one more field jobgroup in table job; I want to combine both jobname and jobgroup and do the same process as mentioned in question above. is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are there multiple possible jobnames for a given jobgroup?

Comment: Yes Its like development and Testing belong to Gr1 and Research and HR belong to Gr2. My result should be like below
Cityid  jobname    Group count avg-sal
10       development    Gr1  2     1500
10       TESTING        Gr1  0       0
10       RESEARCH   Gr2    0       0
10       HR          Gr2  1      2000
10      total         3      1666.66
20      development     Gr1 0         0
20      Testing         Gr1  0         0
20      Research     Gr2     1      1500
20      HR          Gr2      0         0
20      Total          1     2500
Grand Total            4     1625

Comment: Having that situation makes it a lot more complex. I suggest you ask another question (on the upside, if you accept an answer to that too you'll get another 2 rep points)

Comment: Nick - I posted a question. Can you see that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY ROLLUP` like following.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN cityid IS NOT NULL 
              AND jobname IS NULL THEN 'Total' 
         WHEN cityid IS NULL 
              AND jobname IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total' 
         ELSE Cast(cityid AS VARCHAR(100)) 
       END CityId, 
       jobname, 
       [count], 
       [avg_sal] 
FROM   (SELECT e.cityid, 
               j.jobname, 
               Count(*) [Count], 
               Avg(sal) [Avg_Sal] 
        FROM   job J 
               INNER JOIN emp E 
                       ON e.jobid = j.jobid 
        GROUP  BY rollup ( e.cityid, j.jobname )) t
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/JFL94406)

Edit: For All the `JOBNAME`,s you need to use `CROSS JOIN` to get all the combinations  like following query.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT JOBNAME, E.CITYID, SUM(CASE WHEN J.JOBID=E.JOBID  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) M
     , AVG(CASE WHEN J.JOBID=E.JOBID AND E.CITYID=E.CITYID THEN SAL ELSE null END) AVG_Sal
        FROM EMP E
        CROSS JOIN JOB J
        GROUP BY JOBNAME, E.CITYID
    ),
     CTE1 AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT JOBNAME, E.CITYID
        FROM EMP E
        CROSS JOIN JOB J    
    )
    SELECT
    case when CITYID is not null and JOBNAME is null then 'Total' 
         when cityid is null and JOBNAME is null AND [Avg_Sal] IS NOT NULL then 'Grand Total'
         else cast(cityid as varchar(100))
         end CityId
         ,JOBNAME
         ,[Count]
         ,[Avg_Sal]
     from 
    (
        SELECT e.CITYID,j.JOBNAME,SUM(M) [Count], avg([Avg_Sal]) [Avg_Sal]
         FROM CTE  J
        INNER JOIN  CTE1 E on  E.CITYID=J.CITYID AND J.JOBNAME=E.JOBNAME
        GROUP BY ROLLUP (e.CITYID,j.JOBNAME) 
    ) t
```

[**Demo 2**](https://rextester.com/VYYLO97033)

**Output**

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| CityId      | JOBNAME     | Count | Avg_Sal |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 10          | DEVELOPMENT | 2     | 1500    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 10          | HR          | 1     | 2000    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 10          | RESEARCH    | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 10          | TESTING     | 1     | 1000    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Total       | NULL        | 4     | 1500    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 20          | DEVELOPMENT | 1     | 2500    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 20          | HR          | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 20          | RESEARCH    | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 20          | TESTING     | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Total       | NULL        | 1     | 2500    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 30          | DEVELOPMENT | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 30          | HR          | 1     | 1000    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 30          | RESEARCH    | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 30          | TESTING     | NULL  | NULL    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Total       | NULL        | 1     | 1000    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| Grand Total | NULL        | 6     | 1600    |
+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for reply; It is returning only for the  matching jobid's; for non matching jobid's count and avg sal should be 0 as shown in expected result above .

Comment: You can always put a left join for that case, ideally I suggest you should be doing such thing in UI, not in the DB

Comment: i tried thru left join but its not giving correct results.
otherwise is it better to use cursor ?

Comment: @SRI, i have updated my answer, you can have a look and let me know if you are getting the expected results.

Comment: PSK -Thank you ; When I run for large data its not getting all counts; retrieving  less no.of counts than expected

Comment: do you still have issue??